# "permission violation" error when executing a sql server stored procedure on php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I'm using sqlsrv library from PHP to connect to my database and execute a stored procedure. Here's my code:

```
    <?php
$serverName = "myserver";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$tsql_callSP = "{call exec usp_EventsGetByUser(?)}";
$params = array(
        array(1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);

if ($stmt === false)
{
        echo "Error executing statement";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

Connection is successful and I've already given execute permissions to this user in Management Studio using

```
Grant execute on <stored procedure name> to <user name>
```

Comment: can you export your current users' priviledges ?

Comment: Can you try `{call usp_EventsGetByUser(?)}` for your query?

Comment: First, just verify that the login is associated with the database in SSMS.  Also, if the stored procedure has any cross database joins you would need additional permissions in those databases for the login being used.  Otherwise you will get permissions errors.